Possibility to implement multiple repr strategies?
In Python, is there a way to implement multiple repr strategies on custom classes, to provide different representation styles, and that recursively on arbitrary data structures, so nested objects would be shown using the parent call's strategy, if available? Like this...
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, objects):
        self._objects = objects
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Recursive default repr: {self._objects}"
    def __alternate_repr__(self):
        return f"Recursive alternate repr: {self._objects}"

a = SomeClass(["list", "of", "values"])
b = SomeClass(dict(nested_class=a))
c = SomeClass([b, 1, "..."])

repr(c)  # c,b,a shown using __repr__()
alternate_repr(c)  # c,b,a shown using __alternate_repr__()


How would you indicate which repr you want to use?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk The root call would indicate that (in the example: repr() vs alternate_repr()). But perhaps it would be better to imagine a repr function taking a key to use, if available (i.e. repr(...) vs repr(..., key="__alternate_repr__")).

What does this have to do with the repr interface? If you want to write your own method to display your class, you can just do that.

@wjandrea My crystal ball says OP wants something that Just Works with e.g. f"{foo=!r}".

@mara004 But alternate_repr doesn't exist... So do you want to write your own protocol? You can do that, though not using dunder names.

@mara004 Are you aware of _repr_html_ and the other methods used in IPython/Jupyter? Maybe that's what you actually want.

@wjandrea In a complex object graph, that would mean having to re-implement the recursive container traversion and displaying, which is what I want to avoid.

@mara004 If I'm understanding you right, you could factor that out into a method, like _traverse, which would just pass back the contained objects for use by __repr__ and __alternate_repr__

You'd probably want repr() to do the right thing (e.g. when called by other library code), and that code wouldn't know about a __special_repr__ or whatever, so you'll need some more roundabout plumbing here.
Using contextvars makes sure this is async/threading safe.
import contextlib
import contextvars

## Repr mode plumbing.

_repr_mode = contextvars.ContextVar("repr_mode", default="normal")


def get_repr_mode():
    return _repr_mode.get()


@contextlib.contextmanager
def with_repr_mode(mode):
    try:
        token = _repr_mode.set(mode)
        yield
    finally:
        _repr_mode.reset(token)


## Client classes using the repr mode.


class SomeClass(str):
    def __repr__(self):
        if get_repr_mode() == "special":
            return f"SPECIAL ALL CAPS REPR! {self.upper()}"
        return super().__repr__()


class SomeContainer(list):
    def __repr__(self):
        if get_repr_mode() == "special":
            return f"SPECIAL REPR!: {super().__repr__()}"
        return super().__repr__()


## Demo code.

lst = SomeContainer([SomeClass("hello"), SomeClass("world")])

print(repr(lst))

with with_repr_mode("special"):
    print(repr(lst))

This prints out
['hello', 'world']
SPECIAL REPR!: [SPECIAL ALL CAPS REPR! HELLO, SPECIAL ALL CAPS REPR! WORLD]


That's a clever idea, thanks!

Pandas does something like this with option_context(), but it also has a non-context option setter.

IIUC, the equivalent of OP's alternate_repr would be def special_repr(obj: object) -> str: with with_repr_mode("special"): return repr(obj)

You mean something like this?
class Foo:
    def __alt_repr__(self) -> str:
        return "FooAlt()"


class FooSub(Foo): ...


class Bar: ...


def alt_repr(obj: object) -> str:
    if hasattr(obj, "__alt_repr__"):
        return obj.__alt_repr__()
    return repr(obj)


print(alt_repr(Foo()))  # FooAlt()
print(alt_repr(FooSub()))  # FooAlt()
print(alt_repr(Bar()))  # <__main__.Bar object at 0x...>


Not quite, this would not get the recursion right.

Don't use dunder names, they're reserved.

This at least demonstrates that repr itself isn't really special; it's just a function that looks for a particular method on its argument. (Other functions, like len, copy, deepcopy, etc, work the same.) The only thing special about repr is that the Python interpreter itself (in interactive mode) will  automatically invoke repr on the value of an expression evaluated at the prompt.

@mara004 It's not illustrated here, but a class's __alt_repr__ would need to call alt_repr on any contained objects. That's exactly how a custom __repr__ works.

@wjandrea Then how would you hand this down throughout the container? Say, if the object has a list and we call alt_repr() on that, it would not apply on elements in the list anymore. So we'd have to traverse the list ourselves, call alt_repr() on each element, and build the list string manually. And the same for any other containers, like dict or set. You can see how tedious that would get, and that this would have to re-implement existing semantics (like the brackets and comma-separation for list). And you wouldn't be able to support generic iterables without losing their own representation.

@mara004 Ahhh, I see! Now I understand the purpose of the question! You should edit that in! :)

@mara004 Now that I read it again, I see you basically did show that already in the code, but it's not explained in words. I also got hung up on alternate_repr not existing.

It occurred to me we might be able to temporarily replace the builtins repr with an alt_repr as shown in this post. While this would avoid overhead in the default repr case, it would cause significantly more overhead in the alternate case, because we'd have to check for __alt_repr__ on every single object. This is probably the reason why repr() does not provide an argument to look for alternate functions, so I suppose @AKX's approach is the way to go.

I also wondered whether we could get an __alt_repr__ into the object base class, defaulting to repr(self) so we could simply call __alt_repr__ for all objects (also temporarily patching the builtins repr). This would seem like the most overhead-free solution, but I'm not aware of a way to alter object like that.

What I forgot to point out in my other comment, the issue of losing an object's own repr is not only with generic iterables, but in fact with any custom class (which is a container) - say, an attrs class, or a subclass of a primitive (e.g. list). When re-implementing the object graph traversal, you'd either lose the alternate repr or the class's custom repr. So this is definitely not the way to go.
